# What size air hose would a mechanic's garage require?

Tags: compressor, hose

I'm looking for a retractable air hose for my husband as a birthday present...he is an airplane mechanic and has many air tools, also has a large air compressor already (not sure of the hp, but it is 220 volt). I have my eye on a unit called Zillareel that offers 150 psi,(another unit offers 300 psi) would that be enough to psi to supply the air for anything my husband would need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

150 PSI is supposed to be fine for most tools and compressors because most are rated for 125 PSI.  **But** a lot of shops like to run at a little higher PSI like 150+ because it gives the tool more power.  The PSI rating of the hose needs to be higher than what he runs his tools at.  I would recommend the 300 PSI one because in addition to higher pressure, it is probably more durable because it has thicker sidewalls.

When I read 'size' in the question title, I immediately thought about the inner diameter (ID) of the hose.  A lot of people/mechanics/shops overlook the diameter of the hose, but it robs them of power at the top end of performance which is exactly where you need the power!  Get as large of an inner diameter (ID) as you can afford.  It will be listed like (in increasing size order) 1/4", 3/8", 1/2", 5/8", etc.

And of course, longer is better too!

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the pressure figures you are referring to. What you are probably referencing is the pressure *rating* of the reel units, this is the pressure they can operate at safely (without the hose bursting or some other unfortunate dangerous failure).

The air delivery capacity will be expressed by a quantity per unit of time, like "liters per minute" or "cubic feet per minute". Generally, larger hose can deliver more air and some types of tools need a lot of air (like rotary air tools). Can you find out what pressure he operates his unit at? If I were you I would default to the old idea that "bigger is better", or just ask him which one he would like. Most men very much appreciate nice tools for gifts, whether or not it is a suprise.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Zach...you brought up a point that I had not thought of asking, I didn't think about the inner diameter, and I will put 1/2 size (or larger) on my shopping list! Also will look for 300 psi-- I appreciate the time you took to answer my question, I have learned some good info from you! Thanks again to you, and Jimmy Fix-it(that guys like tools whether surprise, or not)! 
This is a great site, and I will keep it bookmarked for any future questions I might have!!

Comment: This should be a comment under Zach's answer.